# DVD/CD driver missing during Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, dvd

I have an Optiplex GX620 that I'm trying to install Windows 7 Pro 64bit on. I've attempted to do so using a DVD and a flash drive (with the DVD/CD drive completely disconnected. In both cases I get the same error, right after selecting the language etc and clicking install it pops up a box stating that a required DVD/CD driver is missing... which doesn't make a whole lot of sense considering the DVD drive isn't even connected when installing from the flash drive. I have no idea what driver to look for since it clearly isn't the DVD driver. I even tried installing from another, external, DVD drive just to eliminate the possibility of the USB having issues. What can I do to correct this error? Thanks

EDIT: Ended up using the 32bit version instead and it worked great.

Comment: Consider that it may be part of the install process to load a driver in order to probe the hardware. My guess is that is is actually telling you that it does not have a driver for the AHCI SATA controller which communicates with the drives. (dell would have them)

Comment: Hmm, good idea, I'll look and see if I can find a sata driver for that board that is compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Actually it seems a Windows 7 compatible driver was never released for that board. Any other ideas?

Comment: The only other thoughts I have is that you have missing or corrupt file(s) on your image. According to the internets ( http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19451757.aspx ), a gx620 should "work." The link states that packages from other dell systems have the proper drivers, none of the items in that thread look like pre-install drivers, and I see no complaints of needing to insert a driver disk to get setup working.

Comment: also: another thought is looking for and PATA/IDE/ETC compatability mode for any sata drives, but that would most likely choke performance.

Comment: I looked through the forum post you linked to and one person suggested using 32bit instead of 64 if you have less than 4gb of RAM, it does so I gave it a shot and it ended up working! At least so far. Seems crazy but it did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not relating to the OP's problem, but I got same error installing 32 bit Win7, but 64 bit has installed without a hitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoted my comments to an "answer":

Consider that it may be part of the install process to load a driver in order to probe the hardware. My guess is that is is actually telling you that it does not have a driver for the AHCI SATA controller which communicates with the drives. (dell would have them)

The only other thoughts I have is that you have missing or corrupt file(s) on your image. According to the internets ( en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/… ), a gx620 should "work." The link states that packages from other dell systems have the proper drivers, none of the items in that thread look like pre-install drivers, and I see no complaints of needing to insert a driver disk to get setup working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while installing Windows 7 SP1 Pro x64 on a Q67 based Intel mainboard. The problem was that I kept using a `USB 3.0` port to connect the DVD drive and the later the memory stick. Once I changed to a `USB 2.0` port the installation succeeded.

The Dell Optiplex GX620 doesn't seem to have USB3 ports, so in your case this was probably caused by something else.